# Best practice or recommended approach for handling Exception in azure service bus?

Tags: azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-subscriptions

Given that

```
 SessionLockLostException and MessageLockLostException are expected exceptions and the user is expected to handle those scenarios irrespective of whether there is a subscription update happening or not.
The lock is in-memory and can be lost when nodes restart, or when containers move due to load-balancing or if there are any transient communication issues.
```

What is the recommended way of handling those exceptions given we do not want to loose the messages?

Answer (score 0):

Messages are not lost when using `PeekLock` receive mode. Unless the mode is changed to `ReceiveAndDelete`. By default, operations should be to retry the message. When the lock or session lock is lost, the message will be delivered next time. This does mean building your processor in a way that allows idempotent processing.